# Double-click to open files in localhost from Windows 7 explorer?

Tags: php, html, windows-7, localhost

Is there a way to open files in localhost automatically when you double click them in Windows 7?

For example, I have a huge directory of projects and it's a pain to open them up & then change the file:/// structure to localhost on each open.

It'd be great to be able to just double-click them in Windows and have them open in 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not what you're looking for, but it's an idea at least.

Write a little program (possibly a batch file) that takes a file as an argument and opens it in your browser via localhost (you'll have to do some path altering).

Then set the default program associated with your HTML (or whatever) files to be the program you just made.

Comment: I've just tried it and you can set a batch file as the default program for a particular file type in windows 7. You can also open webpages quite easily from a batch file - just google how to open pages from command line for whatever browser you use. From there you just have to figure out how to edit the file path to match the URL you need.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I only know Web languages. No clue how to write a batch file. Still, I'll look into it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `Localhost Automate` Google Chrome extension.
It can be found on chrome web store for free.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/localhost-automate/pplnfonehjimoddpmnhldhkgojhkjcfh/related?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon